# Day of tomorrow's show date in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add days to DateTime using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime-using-javascript)

if today's date of 5-12-2012, I want to display the date the next day 6-12-2012. How is that coded in javascript?

Comment: Its not a tough one. But the thing is what have you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var date = "5-12-2012";
var datum = new Date(date);
datum.setDate(datum.getDate() + 1);
date = datum.getDate() + "-" + (datum.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + datum.getFullYear();
```